# My NodeJS initialisation is giving an odd error and not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node.JS from the [W3Schools tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_intro.asp), and I am extremely confused as to why my initialisation is not working. I made one file:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

and initialised it using the command `node myfirst.js` which is the name of my file. It gave an error, but I then opened `http://localhost:8080` and there was the text `Hello World!`. But when I changed the file:

```
res.end('Goodbye World!');
```

Nothing changed. I always get an error whenever I initialise my Node files, but I can't find anything in the Node.JS docs about it. Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

Here's my error:[image]

Comment: EADDRINUSE means the previous process is still running. If you haven't already, close it. Or else, check the process Id and kill it.

Comment: Ahh! How would I do that? I'm still new to Node

Comment: `lsof -i:8080` to find the PID. (let's say PID is 3234). then `kill -9 3234` to kill the process. However, note that this should not happen frequently. If this happens all the time, there is something else wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: And I suggest to get started with expressJs rather than with raw nodejs.

Comment: Now there's a new error: EACCES It does not let me start a `node` process, it just cuts to blank command line, not even computer name or a chevron. I do not know what's happening, any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179225/discussion-between-jbdouble05-and-pubudu-dodangoda).

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda I am unable to kill the process, and now it's been moved off the localhost server. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JBDouble05 please explain the following in a single comment: What exactly do you run? What exactly is the output of the command?  What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the response I got from @PubuduDodangoda said that I need to run this in my command line:

```
lsof -i:8080
kill -9 [result from above command]
```

My code now works perfectly, thanks @PubuduDodangoda!